# Image upload crop resize save to folder

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I want from user to upload an image of any size for (jpg,png,gif) format. After uploading the image I want him to crop the image (client side) using jquery and save that cropped image (php) to application folder.

Please tell me the feasible solution to make this functionality working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick is used for croping images:

http://www.sitepoint.com/crop-and-resize-images-with-imagemagick/

For using ajax:

http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php

Comment: Thanks for your reply but, I want to ask user to crop his/her uploaded image. I have the code written in php to crop on the basis of the dimensions provided by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have the PHP code to crop, use one of this plugins to allow the user define how she wants to crop the image and provide the data you need:

- [Guillotine](http://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine): Very lightweight plugin that allows to crop, zoom and rotate images with touch support and it's responsive ([demo](http://matiasgagliano.github.io/guillotine)).
- [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html): Allows free selection cropping ([demo](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php)).

Answer (score 0):

It is simple image crop using jquery and php using cropbox.js

Please watch the following video

[Simple image crop](https://youtu.be/nJTiLGrrnzA)